# google cloud DNS zone mapping from naked to www URL

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I am trying to get my naked domain URL example.com to map to  www.example.com. Can someone please give me the step by step procedure to get this working. I can't get it working, no matter what I try

Here is my setup:

1) Domain is registered on GoDaddy, the GoDaddy DNS is pointing to google (ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com etc..)

2) Website is hosted on google cloud storage bucket www.example.com (domain also verified by google domain)

3) Under google cloud DNS, below is my zone file.

```
example.com.    A   3600    
216.239.32.21
216.239.34.21
216.239.36.21
216.239.38.21


example.com.    AAAA    3600    
2001:4860:4802:32::15
2001:4860:4802:34::15
2001:4860:4802:36::15
2001:4860:4802:38::15


example.com.    MX  3600    
0 aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.

example.com.    NS  21600   
ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com.

example.com.    SOA 21600   
ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1       21600 3600 259200 300

www.example.com.    CNAME   3600    
c.storage.googleapis.com.
```

when i go to www.example.com, everything works fine. However when I go to example.com google says "404. That’s an error. The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know."  And if i remove the A and AAAA records, the page just won't load.

All i am looking for is have example.com redirect/forward to www.example.com but cant seem to get it working.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This case should be moved to serverfault as this is a programming related forum.

Comment: Hi how do I move it to “serverfaults”

Answer (score 0):

You may also redirect the A/AAAA record to example.com. You can do that simultaneously from Cloud DNS (GCP). Pointing A record to www.example.com & example.com